# For the Mongo database profiler, is there any difference between levels 0 and 1?

Tags: mongodb

According to Mongo documentation I found here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#profiling-levels

a database profiler level of '0' means

> the profiler is off, does not collect any data. mongod always writes operations longer than the slowOpThresholdMs threshold to its log. This is the default profiler level.

Meanwhile a level of '1' means

> collects profiling data for slow operations only. By default slow operations are those slower than 100 milliseconds.
>   You can modify the threshold for “slow” operations with the slowOpThresholdMs runtime option or the setParameter command. See the Specify the Threshold for Slow Operations section for more information.

I do not see how these are different.  They both only log slow operations, and both look to the same value (slowOpThresholdMs) to do so.

Am I missing something?  If these are indeed the some, does someone know why the options are defined thusly?  I got confused because other parts of the documentation (eg https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) seem to indicate that level 0 means no profiling whatsoever, which is not what I observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible targets for profiler information:

- The Mongod log
- The `system.profile` collection in the database which is being profiled

The `level` controls what is written and where it is written to:

- level 0 means that no output is written to the the `system.profile` collection but Mongo will output information about operations that take longer than the `slowOpThresholdMs` to the Mongo log
- level 1 means that Mongo will write profiler documents to the `system.profile` collection for operations which take longer than `slowOpThresholdMs` **and*** Mongo will print information about operations that take longer than the `slowOpThresholdMs` to the Mongo log

So, the key difference is that profile documents will be written to the `system.profile` collection for level > 0.